# ERROR io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.online.HttpClient - Error HTTP 404 executing https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_116

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdrivermanager-java

I am getting the bellow error when trying to run automation tests, after Chrome was updated from v114 to v116

ERROR io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.online.HttpClient - Error HTTP 404 executing https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_116

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76932496/webdrivermanager-setup-failing-to-download-chromedriver-116/76953473. To solve it, bump to the latest version of WebDriverManager (5.5.0 at the moment of this writing). See more info at https://bonigarcia.dev/webdrivermanager/#known-issues

Answer (score 0):

Update your Selenium version to the latest - 4.11.0. The issue was mentioned in [What's new in Selenium Manager with Selenium 4.11.0](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2023/whats-new-in-selenium-manager-with-selenium-4.11.0/)